# Maven , change in order of profile results different build directory struture 

Tags: java, maven

I am facing very ridiculous problem here i have a `pom.xml` which is being used to build the war file .I have introduced `profile` to work it for different environment`(dev/prod)` .but the problem is when i create build it create correct build directory for the profile which is below in order in `pom.xml`

Please assist what is the issue here.

```
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>lifecycle</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceExcludes>**login.jsp</warSourceExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <directory>target/${lifecycle}</directory>
            <finalName>testapp</finalName>
            <resources>
               <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${lifecycle}</directory>
               </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>lifecycle</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <directory>target/${lifecycle}</directory>
            <finalName>testapp</finalName>
            <resources>
               <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${lifecycle}</directory>
               </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Correct build directory should be

if **-Dlifecycle=dev**

`target/dev/testapp/`

if **-Dlifecycle=prod**

`target/prod/testapp/` but here i get 'target/testapp-xx.x'

why is this different behavior?

**Command to trigger the build:**`mvn clean install -Dlifecycle=prod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an id element to the prod profile fix this.

Comment: Added id element but same issue.

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using?

Comment: Ok I am using version 3.0.2 and its working fine for me. Not sure what the profile support is for profiles in Maven 2.2.1. Looking at the behaviour you are describing the profile config from the command line is not taken into account.

Comment: command i am using is mvn clean install -Dlifecycle=prod and in this case it is creating problem where as for mvn clean install -Dlifecycle=dev is working fine. in case of prod It is creating package with appname followed by version but for dev it is creating package under dev directory with appname.

Comment: Great! What fixed it in the end.

Comment: it was a my silly mistake where id and property were different.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is specify which profile should be built.

Define an ID for each profile:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
...
    <profile>
```

When building, use the argument **-P** to inform maven which profiles to activate

> mvn clean install -P dev

Comment: but i am using mvn clean install -Dlifecycle=prod command where lifecycle identifies the profile name.Any idea what should be done ?

Comment: According to maven site, it seems to be another way of doing it.
I've only worked using -P parameter.
Maven site says: "The result will be a bulleted list of the id of the profile with an activation property of 'env=dev' together with the source where it was declared. See sample below." It suggest you will need to specify profiles IDs.

Comment: Can't you try using -P parameter?